# Adding fragment to layout results in blank UI except for new fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Rookie android dev, inherited an app which works fine.  They want to add simple bottom nav.  Just to see what it might look like, I added some radio buttons into a fragment, included that fragment into the main activity page's layout, and had the main activity class implement the required interface to support the new fragment.  The main activity class extends a custom class which extends FragmentActivity.

Upon running the app with my addition, nothing shows up on the main activity screen except those radio buttons below a blank, white screen.  Worse, if I touch in the blank area, the app responds to the touch, so apparently it thinks it's still displaying the stuff it should be displaying (a map and a list of businesses, and a touch navigates to the touched business's detail page).

Worst of all, there are no compile nor runtime errors.  Not even sure what to Google at this point...any help welcome.  I've tried shrinking the size of the bottom nav all the way down to barely visible, and I've tried shrinking other components on the main page.

Here's the layout of the main page; almost the absolute bottom is where I added the new include :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@color/white" >

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_view_top_margin" 
         android:background="@color/white">

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/mapContents"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:visibility="invisible" >

             <fragment
                 android:id="@+id/map"
                 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                 map:cameraTargetLat="41.7150"
                 map:cameraTargetLng="-77.1625"
                 map:cameraZoom="10"/>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/mapButtons"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:alpha="0"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:padding="@dimen/content_view_padding" >

                 <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/mapCenterLocation"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="20"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                     style="@style/GreenButtonLargeText"
                     android:src="@drawable/map_home_arrow"/>

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/mapRedoSearch"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="60"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                     style="@style/GreenButtonLargeText"
                     android:text="Redo Search Here" />

                 <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/mapCashBackToggle"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="20"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                     style="@style/GreenButtonLargeText"
                     android:src="@drawable/icon_percentage"/>

             </LinearLayout>
         </RelativeLayout>

         <ListView
             android:id="@+id/lvBusinesses"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
             android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
             android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
             android:overScrollMode="never"
             android:visibility="invisible" />

         <include 
             layout="@layout/no_results_found_layout"/>

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/llLoading"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
             android:padding="20dp"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imgSteam"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:background="@drawable/loading_animation" />

             <ImageView 
                 android:id="@+id/imgLoader"
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="49dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvLoading"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:text="Loading..." />
         </LinearLayout>     

     </RelativeLayout>

     <include android:id="@+id/include_header"
         layout="@layout/header" />

     <!-- this is the only change Ive made -->
     <include android:id="@+id/include_bottom_nav"
         layout="@layout/bottom_nav" />
     <!-- end change -->

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/searchFragmentHolder"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the bottom nav piece I included (include_bottom_nav.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/b_nav_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.activity.BottomNavFragment"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
```

Which references this fragment (BottomNavFragment.java):

```
 package com.example.activity;

 import com.example.R;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.CompoundButton;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;


 public class BottomNavFragment extends Fragment
 {

     private View fragmentView;

     private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

     /**
      * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
      * this fragment using the provided parameters.
      *
      * @return A new instance of fragment BottomNavFragment.
      */
     public static BottomNavFragment newInstance ()
     {
         BottomNavFragment fragment = new BottomNavFragment ();
         Bundle args = new Bundle ();
         fragment.setArguments ( args );
         return fragment;
     }

     public BottomNavFragment ()
     {
         // Required empty public constructor
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
     {
         super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
     }

     RadioButton radioButton1;
     RadioButton radioButton2;
     RadioButton radioButton3;
     RadioButton radioButton4;
     RadioButton radioButton5;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState )
     {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         fragmentView =  inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_bottom_nav, container, false );

         radioButton1 = (RadioButton) fragmentView.findViewById ( R.id.btnAll );
         radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
         radioButton2 = (RadioButton) fragmentView.findViewById ( R.id.btnPicture );
         radioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
         radioButton3 = (RadioButton) fragmentView.findViewById ( R.id.btnVideo );
         radioButton3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
         radioButton4 = (RadioButton) fragmentView.findViewById ( R.id.btnFile );
         radioButton4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
         radioButton5 = (RadioButton) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);
         radioButton5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);

         return fragmentView;

     }

     public void toggleButton( CompoundButton buttonView )
     {
         if ( null == buttonView )
         {
             System.out.println ( "null button view -- wtf" );
             return;
         }

         switch ( buttonView.getId () )
         {
             case R.id.btnPicture:
                 radioButton2.setButtonDrawable ( R.drawable.navbar_pictureselected );
                 break;
             case R.id.btnMore:
                 radioButton5.setButtonDrawable ( R.drawable.navbar_moreselected );
                 break;
             case R.id.btnAll:
                 radioButton1.setButtonDrawable ( R.drawable.navbar_allselected );
                 break;
             case R.id.btnFile:
                 radioButton4.setButtonDrawable ( R.drawable.navbar_fileselected );
                 break;
             case R.id.btnVideo:
                 radioButton3.setButtonDrawable ( R.drawable.navbar_videoselected );
                 break;
         }

     }

     private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
     {
         public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
         {
             Intent i = null;

             if (isChecked)
             {
                 if ( mListener != null )
                 {
                     switch ( buttonView.getId () )
                     {
                      //  do nav here later 
                     }
                     mListener.onFragmentInteraction ( buttonView, i );
                 }
             }
         }
     };


     @Override
     public void onAttach ( Activity activity )
     {
         super.onAttach ( activity );
         try
         {
             mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
         } catch ( ClassCastException e )
         {
             throw new ClassCastException ( activity.toString ()
                     + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener" );
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach ()
     {
         super.onDetach ();
         mListener = null;
     }

     /**
      * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
      * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
      * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
      * activity.
      * <p/>
      */
     public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
     {
         public void onFragmentInteraction ( CompoundButton buttonView, Intent intent );
     }

 }
```

Definitely in over my head.  Thanks for any guidance.

EDIT:  request for the fragment_bottom_nav.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
     <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:background="@drawable/navbar_background"
         >
         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/btnAll"
             style="@style/navbar_button"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_allselector"
             android:text="All"
             />
         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
             style="@style/navbar_button"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_pictureselector"
             android:text="Pictures"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             />
         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
             style="@style/navbar_button"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_videoselector"
             android:text="Videos"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             />
         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/btnFile"
             style="@style/navbar_button"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_fileselector"
             android:text="Files"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             />
         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/btnMore"
             style="@style/navbar_button"
             android:drawableTop="@drawable/navbar_moreselector"
             android:text="More"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             />
     </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You inherited an awful layout: the faire of layout nesting!

Comment: Could you share the `fragment_bottom_nav` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `fragment_bottom_nav.xml`- move the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` line from the `RadioGroup` to the parent `RelativeLayout` (also, you probably want the height of the `RelativeLayout` to be `wrap_content` and not `match_parent`). When/if you are checking it out in Android Studio designer, make sure to take a look at the main layout, not at the `fragment_bottom_nav.xml` (here it will look all aligned to the top)

Comment: Thanks, N.T., that's the first bit of progress in 3 days.  Now, the header (in the main activity class's xml layout, it's the include directly above the include that I added) is now appearing.   
Nothing else is appearing (the map nor the business list).  Interestinly, touches on the blank part of the screen still register, but they don't do anything (before they would navigate as if the business list was visible) except in LogCat, it says, "08-20 10:00:23.527: D/ViewRootImpl(9994): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN".  

But anyways, I'll play around with the layout some more -- thanks again

Comment: On Android Studio you can go to Tools->Android->AndroidDeviceMonitor. Once it's up, you can select your app and load the UI hierarchy (Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator) - over there you could see more clearly which layout is at fault.

Comment: Thanks again, N.T.  I didn't even know about that tool